# Colors not showing up in Flutter

Tags: flutter, colors, flutter-layout

I was trying to give my Container a Color but but it's saying, for example: `red is not defined for the type 'Color'`.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:color/color.dart';


class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          Container(
            color: Color.red,
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:color/color.dart';


class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          Container(
            color: Colors.red,
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's `Colors`, not `Color`.

You can look up the Color Class on the [official documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Colors-class.html).

```
Container(
  color: Colors.red,
)
```